# Event handler: leave on or turn off and on as needed?

Tags: jquery, events, handler

I'm using JQuery to have an animated scroll when nav elements on a certain page are clicked (all pages are in the same document, so I'm only hiding content).

Currently I'm turning the event handler on when the page is loaded, and off when the page is "unloaded".

My question: is it more expensive to leave the event handler on (e.g. turn it on at document.ready) or to turn it on and off as I'm doing now?

```
        /* *** SOFTWARE PAGE: NAV CLICK SCROLL *** */
            if(pageSetup.hash.title === "#Software")
                softwareNav.on("click.softScroll", function() {
                    var target = $("#"+$(this).attr("id").slice(0,-3)+"Target");

                    $('html').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top-166
                    }, 1000);
                });
            else if($(".previousPage section").attr("id") === "#softwareContent") softwareNav.off("click.softScroll");
```

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to remove Events, if you're leaving the page anyways, since they won't be triggered.

Comment: If you're just hiding and showing content (while staying in the same browser window), then it's more expensive to add/remove the event listener.  It costs nothing to have it sitting on an idle and hidden element.  Just leave it there.

Comment: @PHPglue - as jfriend00 said, I'm hiding and showing content, not actually leaving the page.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks! I'll leave it on then :)